# Map function in rendering arrays in react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native

I know when we use map function it runs till the end of the array.What I want to know is  there any way to stop it after running it for 5 /10 etc. times

Comment: I would suggest you use a regular `for` loop instead of `map` function.

Comment: Take a slice of the array first? `arr.slice(0, 5).map(...`

Answer (score 0):

No, `Map` will always runs on each element of the array. Instead if you can do is that filter out your array elements based on some condition and then after use `Map` on the result.